# gradient estimations on variational quantum algorithms

Tags: quantum-circuit, vqe

Other than the two famous parameter-shift rule and finite difference method, is there any other (perhaps simple) methods to estimate gradients of a cost function in variational quantum algorithms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One scheme that's been used quite successfully in practice is [SPSA](https://www.jhuapl.edu/spsa/). If you're using a simulator and keeping track of the entire state vector, another really efficient method is [adjoint differentiation](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.02823).